# How to create and set a continuous query in InfluxDB usind Java?

Tags: java, influxdb, continuous

I'm writing a Benchmark to compare several Time Series Databases, and one of the criteria tested is the data Downsampling efficiency. According to InfluxDB's documentation, it is done by creating a second database with a different retention policy that is regularly filled by a continuous query.
The thing is that I can't find anywhere the method to create a continuous query from the Java API. Does anyone know this method ?